# Why is the float object not callable in this situation?

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import math as m
def distance(list1_features, list2_features):
    distance = (list1_features - list2_features)
    """The Euclidean distance between two arrays of feature values."""
    
    return m.sqrt(np.sum((distance)**2))`enter code here`
distances_btw_song=[]
for index, row in lyrics.iterrows():
    point1= np.array(lyrics.iloc[0:1,3:])
    point2=np.array(lyrics.iloc[0:1,3])
    distances=distance(point1,point2)
    
    distances_btw_song.append(distances)
lyrics["Distance"]= distances_btw_song
lyrics.head()
```

I got this code from my partner and we are both using the same code however when the code reaches the distance(point1,point2) it gives me float object not callable but when my partner ran it, he got the table.

DataBase:
[image: Dataset]

Traceback
[image: Traceback]

Comment: You reused the name `distance` to store the difference between the two arguments. Is there a possible indentation error?

Comment: @chepner, isn't it local to the `distance` function?

Comment: @ForceBru That's why I asked about possible indentation errors.  It could also be a typo in the actual code that isn't reproduced here.

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace of the error, as well as a [mre]; this code doesn't seem problematic.

Answer (score 0):

The reuse of the variable distance is likely the culprit, though you should include more data about the error, like a stack trace. You somehow have the value of distance set to a float instead of a function.  Depending on how you're running your code, there's a few ways this might accidentally happen.  Again, you need to include more context around how the error occurred, not just the code and an error.

Comment: I also thought the reuse of variables would be the problem but it still gave out the same error also I think it might be the points it is grabbing I have included the traceback and dataset as well

Comment: The full stack trace, not just the last bit of it, and don't use screenshots, it's really un-user-friendly for anyone who might help you.  Your question omits some things that happen first, and without the full context, you'll likely not get much help.  

Low-tech approach: add a bunch of print("var ==", var) throughout the code and see what variable values are at various stages.  you might be surprised.

Comment: That is the full stack trace why would I use the last bit of it

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was the problem I just changed

```
def distance(list1_features, list2_features):
```

to this

```
def euclidean_distance(list1_features, list2_features):
```